# Rails 4 Autocomplete with Simple Form - class parameter ignored

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, jquery-autocomplete

I am using Simple Form, along with the Rails Autocomplete gem.

I have a straightforward form control, where the autocomplete is working as intended:

```
<%= f.input :practice, as: :autocomplete, url: autocomplete_practice_name_shifts_path, id_element: '#shift_practice_id', class: 'form-control'  %>
```

This works perfectly, except that the `class: 'form-control'` parameter is not being translated onto the form.

If I remove the autocomplete parameters like so:

```
<%= f.input :practice, id_element: '#shift_practice_id', class: 'form-control'  %>
```

The class carries through correctly; as such, it seems to be the autocomplete option that is overriding the class.

Can anybody advise what the correct way to set the class on this input is?

Comment: pass it like `input_html: { class: 'form-control' }` ..

Comment: Thanks - please post this as an answer so I can mark it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pass it like :

```
input_html: { class: 'form-control' }
```